# In Javascript, writes a function to detect the type of a variable is a String?

Tags: javascript, function

In Javascript, writes a function to detect the type of a variable is a String.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for that in JS.

Just use typeof(variable_name) == "string" and you should be good to go!!